# Git Branch Merging Mistake

Tags: git, git-merge

[image]

Does anyone happen to know how I can get back to remotes/origin/develop?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Which branch do you want to "get back to `origin/develop`"?

Be sure you have the right branch checked out (here, it's hard to tell from the screenshot. I've assumed it's `develop` you want to roll back) and do

```
git reset --hard origin/develop
```

to make the branch return to that state.

**Two warnings**, though :

1) It rewrites the history of your branch, so if you happened to have pushed your branch* in the meantime, you'll have to go for another strategy.

2) *Before* doing any of this, be sure to have saved your uncommited changes in some way, either by stashing or commiting. A hard reset *is* undoable, but only the branch-pointing part. Uncommited changes would be *really* lost.

* *(obviously not if the branch is* `develop`, *but it **is** the case for*  `sem2`*)*

Comment: Ok, that seems to be exactly what I would like. Let me try and get back to you. Thank you.